# What term refers to "one's personal definition of what is polite or rude"?

Tags: single-word-requests

People tend to have their own feelings about what behavior or conversation subjects are polite or rude. Is there a specific term to refer to a person's personal definitions of this? The terms "ethics", "morals", and "virtues" don't seem specific enough in dealing just with this sense.

Comment: Perhaps all personal definitions come under one's *culture*. However, this is less of a question of language than sociology. Maybe sociolinguistics. Why not ask on [linguistics.se]?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the word you seek is 'sensibilities.'

From [TFD:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensibility)

> Receptiveness to impression, whether pleasant or unpleasant; acuteness of feeling. Often used in the plural: "The sufferings of the Cuban people shocked our sensibilities" (George F. Kennan).

The implication is that some other group may not have their own sensibilities shocked by the same thing. It then follows that "One's own sensibilities" would determine what an individual perceives as polite, rude, annoying, etc.

Comment: Even *sensibilities* would need to be qualified with *one's* for the required implication. So there's a problem again. :)

Comment: @Kris: I would contend no more so than 'ethics', 'morals' or 'virtues.'  'Sensibilities,' without attribution to an individual or group would refer the the collection of feelings itself -- the 'receptiveness to impression' mentioned in the definition cited.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: So how's it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

"Etiquette"? "Protocol"? "Manners"? "Taste", even?

Comment: See my comment at MrWonderful's answer.